# Open Modal Dialog in the parent page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a webpart added to a page which has onclick function in it. Upon click of the button a modal dialog shows up. My Requirement is that I have to show up the modal dialog on the page where the webpart is present instead of showing it in the webpart?

Comment: Is the web part a custom web part you developed or a standard web part? we need more info.

Comment: Its actually an app part put which has been put in the SharePoint page.